# custom actions for inherited_resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, inherited-resources

I have 3 custom actions for my controller and was hoping that each of these use the resource object that inherited_resources gives us. So basically, instead of:

```
def cancel
  @job = resource.cancel!
end

def restart
  @job = resource.restart!
end

def start
  @job = resource.start!
end
```

I want to just skip that by:

```
def cancel
  @job.cancel!
end

def restart
  @job.restart!
end

def start
  @job.start!
end
```

Problem with this is @job comes out nil. So I checked the documentation and found out about custom actions. So I added this to my controller:

```
custom_actions :resource => [:cancel, :start, :restart]
```

but @job still is nil. I also tried:

```
actions :all
```

to tell IR to apply resource to all actions and it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap the call like this:

```
def cancel
  cancel! do
    @job.cancel!
  end
end
```

This causes IR to run and then yield control to your block (with the resource already set).

Comment: ah..well if that's the case im good with resource.cancel...since that's fewer characters heh.